# Where should I start reading about aesthetics philosophy?

Tags: aesthetics

I am totally new to philosophy (actually studying engineering) but the philosophy of aesthetics fascinates me.
Which books should I start reading to study about the way socio-economic factors influence the concept of beauty?
I heard that Kant is one of the first to write about it, is it beginner friendly?
Edit: Thank you all guys for the responses, I will try to read as many books that you have recommended me as I can

Comment: first book i read was about aesthetic detachment in japanese art. what is your favourite art? how much of an engineer are you? etc

Comment: Start here: [SEP, The Concept of the Aesthetic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aesthetic-concept/). It gives a historical introduction (including Kant), overview of main themes and many references to further reading.

Comment: This is a very important essay from the American side of the pond, http://www.sharecom.ca/greenberg/kitsch.html  Greenberg was a huge influence on the American Art scene up until the early 1980s. 1939 until the early 80’s and the great “switch” to the New Criterion Art Journal. This history of art theory in America is a good thing to have in your pocket.

Comment: Another good book (taking off from the socio-economic angle) is “The Necessity of Art” by Ernst Fischer. https://archive.org/details/necessityofartma0000fisc

Comment: This YouTube video may interest you. Regarding Film, which of course was the major new art form of the last century. “Todd Haynes From Fassbinder to Sirk and back” https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZTrOQL23XY

Comment: (Rainer Werner Fassbinder; Douglas Sirk)

Comment: Kant is not “beginner friendly”.  However, you may want to read this:  Immanuel Kant: Aesthetics at IEP https://www.iep.utm.edu/kantaest/

Comment: if i may say -- gordon -- for users of the site such as myself, links to articles or essays would be preferable to book length studies [alas]

Answer (score 2):

One very good and non-technical introductory anthology of essays on the subject,  edited by the novelist (See *Foucault's Pendulum and Name of the Rose*, both of which which I highly recommend)  public intellectual and semioticist, is  Umberto Eco's 2004 *The History of Beauty* [https://www.amazon.com/History-Beauty-Umberto-Eco/dp/0847835308](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0847835308).  Here's a little blurb about the book:

> Umberto Eco’s groundbreaking and much-acclaimed first illustrated book
> has been a critical success since its first publication in 2004. What
> is beauty? Umberto Eco, among Italy’s finest and most important
> contemporary thinkers, explores the nature, the meaning, and the very
> history of the idea of beauty in Western culture. The profound and
> subtle text is lavishly illustrated with abundant examples of sublime
> painting and sculpture and lengthy quotations from writers and
> philosophers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are "totally new to philosophy," I recommend you books that aim specifically at such a readership and present the key ideas and basic concepts clearly in a systematic manner. Otherwise, you may get the illusion that you have read and learnt a lot, while failing to grasp fundamentals.

One such good book I myself have read is *Philosophy of Art:A Contemporary Introduction* by Noël Carroll published in the Routledge Contemporary Introductions to Philosophy series (I recommend this series for other subjects as well.) The following is from the book description:

> Philosophy of Art is a textbook for undergraduate students interested
> in the topic of philosophical aesthetics.
>
> It introduces the techniques of analytic philosophy as well as key
> topics such as the representational theory of art, formalism,
> neo-formalism, aesthetic theories of art, neo-Wittgensteinism, the
> Institutional Theory of Art. as well as historical approaches to the
> nature of art.
>
> Throughout, abstract philosophical theories are illustrated by
> examples of both traditional and contemporary art including frequent
> reference to the avant-garde in this way enriching the readers
> understanding of art theory as well as the appreciation of art.

Answer (score 1):

A good book to go to would be Routledge Handbook of Aesthetics. It covers various topics, written by the top scholars, and at the end of each section, they give a very good reference list for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with a comment

> a part of Western bourgeois society has produced something unheard of
> heretofore: -- avant-garde culture. A superior consciousness of
> history -- more precisely, the appearance of a new kind of criticism
> of society, an historical criticism -- made this possible. This
> criticism has not confronted our present society with timeless
> utopias, but has soberly examined in the terms of history and of cause
> and effect the antecedents, justifications and functions of the forms
> that lie at the heart of every society.

Greenberg goes on to discuss kitsch art, art for those who

> are hungry nevertheless for the diversion that only culture of some
> sort can provide... the bad, up-to-date old

http://www.sharecom.ca/greenberg/kitsch.html

He explains that avant garde art "imitates" imitation, and kitsch imitates the "effects" of art. I'd  gloss that as e.g., poetry that expresses the processes of writing poetry, rather than poetry's values. I suppose you could think of the former as something closer to the puzzled notes of engineers, as opposed to their expressions of success or failure.

I would suggest reading about mimesis and imitation, you should be able to do that without much philosophical help -- perhaps Plato. It's a start.